# Tampering with live network packets

Tags: networking, packets

I've put a lot of time and research into finding a reliable solution for my problem. I am attempting to modify values in packets sent to and from my Iphone, of course I can't directly view and tamper with packets directly from my phone. So I've connected my phone via proxy to my computer (windows) so I could attempt to modify the packets their. Now I can successfully view and save packets but I can't seem to find a way to modify them on the fly.

I've followed many suggestions posted here such as scapy and other tools like it yet I can't seem to get them to work on windows at all, also i'm not sure these tools are even right for my end goal. I am familiar with modifying live packets on programs like WPE Pro, but I don't think that's the right tool for the job.

My question is this, is this the right path for accomplishing my goal? If so do you have a suggestion for tools that may help? If not, where should I begin looking for different solution?

Edit: Specifically I am aiming to alter hex code in the packet. In the http 1.1 packets I want to alter, I know the exact position of a certain group of hex values that translate to a plain text number. For example, say on line 80 is some hex equaling "value:12345". I want to alter that "12345" part to different numbers, keeping everything else the same so my phone will process that different value instead.

Comment: We can't hep you if we have no idea about *what* kind of modification you need to do on the packets. Side note: be sure that libpcap (which scapy or wireshark are based on) *do* work on windows. If that was not the case, then wireshark would not work. So refine the question about the modifications needed.

Comment: Thank you for the response jbm, I've edited the original post, hopefully I've clarified enough to give you an idea of what I'm after, in the meantime I'll ensure that libpcap is correctly installed and functioning and will give scapy another try.